# NodeJS Server Adress 80 already in use ERROR --> Running on debian 10 cloud server with apache2

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, apache2, port

I have an issue I can't resolve for a while now. If anyone has a clue, or could help me via TeamViewer, i'll pay reward of 100$. I need this working Monday.

So. I have a webserver set up on 46.231.206.172
There I initially installed an apache2 webserver to host my website under the domain magnolian.ch

Then I switched to a nodejs server though. So I uninstalled apache2 and instead, install a service for the nodejs server.js file.

This worked great on Port 80.

But now all of a sudden (Dont know why, even back 2 weeks of backups still error...).

When I try to load the site, it times out.
When I manually want to start the server via the command "node server.js" it gives the error:

Adress already in use on port 80.

So i have no clue what I need to do here. I cant find any process with Port 80.

lsof -i :80 returns nothing....

Theres no service running that I can seem to find out...

Any ideas?

Much love
Roger, let me know!

Discord for support: Hunter S. Thompson#0275

Code:

Server.js

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app');
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(80);
```

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const offerRoutes = require('./api/routes/offer');
const contactRoutes = require('./api/routes/contacts');
const userRoutes = require('./api/routes/users');
const aboutRoutes = require('./api/routes/abouts');
const servicesRoutes = require('./api/routes/services');
const newsRoutes = require('./api/routes/news');
const homeRoutes = require('./api/routes/home');
const technoRoutes = require('./api/routes/techno');
const errorRoutes = require('./api/routes/error');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', './api/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use('/offer', offerRoutes);
app.use('/about', aboutRoutes);
app.use('/services', servicesRoutes);
app.use('/news', newsRoutes);
app.use('/techno', technoRoutes);
app.use('/contact', contactRoutes);
app.use('/user', userRoutes);
app.use('/', homeRoutes);
app.use('/*', errorRoutes);

app.listen(80, '127.0.0.1');

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Ohhh and btw: The application works completely fine on my localhost. If I run node server.js on my local computer, its running without any issue. 

So it's not that...

Comment: Hello, from your code, you are listening twice on port / interface,  in the server.js with server.listen() and in the app.js file with app.listen(). Try to comment the app.listen() line and see if it works. Passing the app into the http.createServer should be enough.

Comment: Why it is working on localhost and not on your server, it can be related to network interface settings, etc.. I don't have much experience in these fields